# CoreData using custom tableView cell in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, swift2, xcode7

I would like to begin with saying that I'm new to programming in iOS, so I apologize in advance for what might be a bad question. So I have a UITableView with a custom class for my cell. In this cell, I have two Labels, one that represents an array of Strings and one that represents an array of Integers. I am completely lost when it comes to CoreData, but I tried some code and it seemed to work, only problem is that the labels show up at different rows in the tableView. Take a look at this image and you will hopefully understand:
[My tableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alzoa.png)

So what I want is the "Godis" label to be on the same row as the one that says "111". I have no idea why there is a "0" there, I haven't even added it into the array of integers that i mentioned earlier.

Here is the class for the tableView:

```
class tableViewController: UITableViewController {

var listItems = [NSManagedObject]()

var prisItems = [NSManagedObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MinEntity")

    do {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

        listItems = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    }
    catch {
        print("error")
    }


    do {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

        prisItems = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    }
    catch {
        print("error")
    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MinEntity")

    do {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

        listItems = results as! [NSManagedObject]


    }
    catch {
        print("error")
    }


    do {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

        prisItems = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    }
    catch {
        print("error")
    }



}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return listItems.count

}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CDCell




   cell!.itemListLabel.text = listItems[indexPath.row].valueForKey("item") as? String



    cell?.prisListLabel.text = String(prisItems[indexPath.row].valueForKey("intItem")!)


    return cell!

}
```

This is the code that I use to add the items to the tableView by pressing buttons (this is in another file and class):

```
@IBAction func addGodis(sender: AnyObject) {

    saveItem("Godis", itemToSave2: 111)
    print(listItems)
    print(prisItems)




}


@IBAction func addMat(sender: AnyObject) {
    saveItem("Mat", itemToSave2: 222)
    print(listItems)
    print(prisItems)


}



override func viewDidLoad() {


}



func saveItem(itemToSave : String, itemToSave2 : Int) {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("MinEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    item.setValue(itemToSave, forKey: "item")

    do {

        try managedContext.save()

        listItems.insert(item, atIndex: 0)
    }
    catch{
        print("error")
    }


    let item2 = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    item2.setValue(itemToSave2, forKey: "intItem")

    do {

        try managedContext.save()

        prisItems.insert(item2, atIndex: 0)

    }

    catch {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

I also mentioned earlier that I have a custom class for my UITableViewCell, however, I only have the IBOutlets for my Labels in it so there's no additional code in it.

Just to make it more clear what I actually want:
If you look at the image that I linked, you will see that "Godis" and "111" is not on the same row. Instead, there is a 0 there, which I have no idea why it's there. So what I want is to have the "Godis" and the "111" on the same row in the tableView, and also remove the "0" that is in it. The "0" is not even supposed to be there.

Answer (score 0):

You get double rows because you do two inserts instead of one. You are not configuring the second one, so, logically, it shows an empty label and one with `0`.

There could be other errors in code you are not showing. It is anyway ill-advised to use two arrays to power a table view.

You should be using an `NSFetchedResultsController`, not two arrays. To get started look at the code provided by the Xcode template "Master-Detail".

Comment: Thanks, I'll go learn about the NSFetchedResultsController then!